# How to implement google analytics sdk android v2

Tags: android, eclipse, google-analytics

I want to implement google analytics sdk android v2

I had
Update AndroidManifest.xml
Create your analytics.xml file
But i don't know hot to implement  EasyTracker methods
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/#tracking-methods

I don't know where to put it in my code?
Sorry for my english...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.MailTo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;



    public class MainActivity extends Activity

     {

    private static final String MIME_TYPE_EMAIL = null;
    final Activity activity = this;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
        String scandinavianCharacters = null;
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, scandinavianCharacters, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Učitavanje...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                try {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                try {
                    webView.clearView();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/greska/greska.html");
                super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://mobile.mywebsite.com/test/");

    }
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    { 
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }


    WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed (){

        if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();       
        }
        else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Zatvorite aplikaciju?")
            .setMessage("Da li ste sigurni da želite da izađete?")
            .setPositiveButton("Da", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish(); 
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Ne", null)
        .show();
    }

        }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView view, String url) {
        if(url.startsWith("mailto:")){
            MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
            Intent i = IntentSupport.newEmailIntent(MainActivity.this, mt.getTo(), mt.getSubject(), mt.getBody(), mt.getCc());
            startActivity(i);
            view.reload();
            return true;
        }

            else{
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }
   ;


public static Intent newEmailIntent(Context context, String address, String subject, String body, String cc) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { address });
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
  intent.setType(MIME_TYPE_EMAIL);
  return intent;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the currently selected menu XML resource.
    android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

/** Called when a menu item in the menu is clicked. */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.menuabout:
   Toast.makeText(this, " " +
        " " +
        "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   return true;

  // Generic catch all for all the other menu resources
  default:
   if (!item.hasSubMenu())
       return true;

   break;
 }

 return false;
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two additional functions to your activity. You can add them at the bottom of your class at the very end:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
}
```

The onStart() function is called after onCreate() so it will not affect the existing implementation. onStop() is called when the activity is stopped so it will catch things like your onBackPressed() action to stop the activity.

You can then choose to add additional tracking anywhere in your Activity using the send() functions such as the following:

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().sendEvent("Group", "Name", obj, value);
```

Unrelated by important - you should not be called System.exit(0) in your onBackPressed() function. If this is the only activity in your application, calling finish() will be enough to exit the application.

Comment: I get this:
The method activityStart(MainActivity) is undefined for the type Object